# Java Spring boot web service

Tags: java, spring

***My class***

```java
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImp implements UserRepository {

  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Autowired
  public UserRepositoryImp(EntityManager entityManager) {
    this.entityManager = entityManager;
  }

  @Override
  public Integer getCountByEmail(String email) {
    Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);

    TypedQuery<User> query = session.createQuery("SELECT count(e)  FROM User e WHERE e.email=:email", User.class);
    query.setParameter("email", email);
    return query.executeUpdate();
}
```

***My Postman error***

> "Type specified for TypedQuery [com.TestMobileAppService.TestMobileAppService.Domain.User] is
> incompatible with query return type [class java.lang.Long]; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type specified for TypedQuery
> [com.TestMobileAppService.TestMobileAppService.Domain.User] is incompatible with query return type
> [class java.lang.Long]"

**Please help me what is it problem ???**

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: `select count` returns an integer, but your typed query is expecting a User instance. Change the typed query to have `<Integer>` and update accordingly, or fix your query to return a User not a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Your query in variable `MY_SQL_COUNT_EMAIL` returns a count instead of User object, Change the data type of variable either to Long or Integer, something like given below

    @Override
    public Integer getCountByEmail(String email) {
      Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
      
         TypedQuery<Integer> query = session.createQuery(MY_SQL_COUNT_EMAIL,Class.forName("java.lang.Integer")); //Try this
         TypedQuery<Integer> query = session.createQuery(MY_SQL_COUNT_EMAIL); // OR Try this
         query.setParameter("email", email);    
          return query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

Comment: class forname wants paremeters

Comment: Remove the Class.forName parameter and keep only the query in createQuery method